# conemu + zsh(cygwin) - line update?

Tags: консоль, zsh

При запуске zsh внутри conemu перестает работать обновление строк консоли. Не знаю, как точно называется эта функция.

Например при установке пакманом(по ssh подключаюсь к arch-серваку, на котором тоже zsh с тем же конфигом) или иным менеджером пакетов в консоль выводится прогресс-бар, который постоянно обновляется.

Толи оно раньше работало и я чето задел в настройках, толи обновление установил. Короче теперь вместо обновления существующей строки conemu выводит новую ниже старой. Скрин для понимания прилагается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вернуть нормальное поведение?

Comment: `.zshrc` в студию

Comment: мне то [не жалко](http://pastebin.com/c2MMZyk9), только это бесполезно искать проблему в zshrc. Как я написал выше - через терминал cygwin все работает как надо. Плюс, это давно обкатанный конфиг, который я использую на всех машинах, с которыми работаю(arch, debian, ubuntu, freebsd, ...)

Comment: echo $TERM что выводит?

Comment: в conemu для запуска zsh я использую следующую команду: C:\cygwin64\bin\zsh.exe -l -i -new_console:a. Переменная TERM = cygwin. Попробовал zsh вне conemu(в cmd вроде) - та же проблема с обновлением. А терминал, который установился с cygwin и в котором обновление строк работает, запускается вот так: C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico. TERM = xterm Попробовал этот минтти открыть в conemu - обновление строк работает. Но по опыту использования этого терминала знаю, что он очень багованный и основывать на нем решение проблемы не хочется.

Comment: Так же попробовал zsh запустить в powershell - та же проблема. В принципе направление решения ясно - надо сменить терминал, чтобы он поддерживал unix методы вывода/обновления строк. Какие можете посоветовать альтернативы, кроме минта?

Comment: Кроме того этот mintty не подчиняется настройкам шрифта и цветов, которые я указывал в conemu. Тогда встает вопрос - а существуют ли вообще другие терминалы, кроме cmd и powershell, с которыми может работать conemu? И можно ли conemu научить работать с обновлением unix строк без использования других терминалов? Потому что во всем остальном меня полностью устраивает и связка conemu+cmd

Comment: Просто установите `TERM=xterm`, везде принудительно

Comment: пробовал уже. Почему то в конце строки добавляется перенос на новую строку и знак процента.
echo $TERM

xterm
%
Пробовал и с таким значением - не помогает.
Пробовал так: TERM=xterm
И так: export TERM=$(echo 'xterm')
Пробовал и в консоль писать и в конфиг вставлял.

Comment: попробовал в mintty поменять TERM на cygwin - это не помешало ему обновлять строки. [Скрин](http://i89.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0122/ba/10795a52f6aa7840e36dfd1035758fba.jpg). Так что манипуляции с TERM отклоняются как решение, хотя и странно, что в zsh при смене значения дописываются какие то символы лишние.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](https://github.com/Maximus5/conemu-old-issues/issues/879) описание этой же проблемы на англ.

[Вот](http://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html) инструкция для решения проблемы. Автор ConEmu написал специальные коннекторы, чтобы cygwin и msys2 правильно работали с этим терминалом.